# Missing ) after argument rendering html with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I know this is like basic mistake but need some help over the syntax error. I've been searching for about an hour and still could'nt find the error. It's around the success: function(data) area. Thanks

**Error**

> *Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list*

**Script**

```
$('#form-edit-room').on('submit',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var form_data = $(this);
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: '{{route('room.editRoom')}}',
    data:form_data.serialize(),
    success: function(data){
        $('.post' +data.id).replaceWith(" "+
        "<tr class='post"+data.id+"'>"+
        "<td>"+data.id+"</td>"+ 
        "<td>"+data.name+"</td>"+
        "<td>"+data.max_occupancy+"</td>"+
        "<td>"
        if(data.status=='booked')
        "<span class='badge badge-danger'>Booked</span></td>"+
        else
        "<span class='badge badge-success'>Available</span></td>"+
        "<td>"
            "<a href='#' title='Clear Room' class='text-warning' onclick='clearRoom(+data.id+})'><i class='fas fa-broom'></i></a>"+
        "</td>");
});
```

});

Comment: `replaceWith(" "+`

Comment: I dont think there's the problem. The problem is around the if else statement @Lamanus

Comment: I don't understand. The replaceWith function is not closed and how it could be OK?

Comment: You never close the `$.ajax` call. Also, you have `if/else` inside the expression which is incorrect. You also miss some `+` signs.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this.

```
$('#form-edit-room').on('submit',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var form_data = $(this);
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: '{{route("room.editRoom")}}',
    data:form_data.serialize(),
    success: function(data){
        $('.post' +data.id).replaceWith(`<tr class='post${data.id}'><td>${data.id}</td><td>${data.name}</td><td>${data.max_occupancy}</td><td>`+((data.status=='booked')?`<span class='badge badge-danger'>Booked</span></td>`:`<span class='badge badge-success'>Available</span></td>`)+`<td><a href='#' title='Clear Room' class='text-warning' onclick='clearRoom(${data.id})'><i class='fas fa-broom'></i></a></td>`);
      }
    });
});
```